# Only the fan spins when waking up Windows 10 from sleep

Tags: windows-10, sleep, fan, wake-up

I have these "retired" computers from an office. I upgrade them to Windows 10 and install a graphics card.
All computers have the same mainboard and peripherals. I never had any problem to recondition them. Except for the latest one.

This was the process of refurbishing the computer (I did the same with all the other computers):

-Installed new hard drive

-Installed and activated Windows 7

-Upgraded to Windows 10

-Installed GeForce GTX 660 (or other GTX on other computers)

-Installed newest graphics driver (same bulk driver that supports all GTX)

Windows 10 autamatically goes into sleep mode after a given time. When pressing a keyboard key the fan starts spinning but nothing else happens. The hard disk LED is not indicating any activity and I cannot toggle caps lock. The computer seems to crash. I have to force it to shut down and restart.

As I said all previous computers had the same mainboard (same BIOS firmware). The BIOS settings have been reset. I did not leave any USB devices plugged in except for the mouse and keyboard.

There is no relevant difference between this computer and the others. The only difference might be the newer Windows 10 build that came out.

The only solution right now is to disable sleep mode.

What can I do to find the cause of this problem? Is it maybe an incompatibility between the graphics driver and the energy settings?

Comment: This is a chipset driver problem has nothing to do with the GPU.

Comment: I installed the official chipset driver from ASUS and it didn't help. Also, what is weird is that whenever I start Windows I get to the login screen instead of directly to the desktop. That wasn't the case with previous installations. There's definitely something different with the newest Windows 10 build

Comment: Set your default account to automatically go to the desktop

Comment: @Ramhound The login is not a problem. My point is that Windows changes things for no reason. The fact that the login settings are different with this installation tells me that other settings could have been changed also, which causes the problem I have.